# How to add one project to another(Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I wright english very bad,but I hope you'l try to help me)
There is a problem: have one project that contains another 2 projects(that contains classes I using in main project),when try to compile-there are many fails,because main project couldn't find classes from that projects. I tried to add them from build phases->link binary with files-but it doesn't help me(
Help me please with this problem!Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to tell the compiler where to look for the files using the "Header Search Paths" in the project settings.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 4, this is done through Workspaces. This is a fairly big topic, so I will just link you to Apple's high-level document and a blog post that walks through the process of setting one up.

Apple doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

Walkthrough: http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/06/library-management-with-xcode-workspaces.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them as Target Dependencies instead.